# Laravel 5.1 Dynamic where / orWhere

Tags: php, laravel

I want to build a dynamic where / orWhere statment like this.

```
$matchList = [ 'match1', 'match2', 'match3', 'match4' ];

$query->where('Column', 'Like', 'match1')
->orWhere('Column', 'Like', 'match2')
->orWhere('Column', 'Like', 'match3')
->orWhere('Column', 'Like', 'match4');
```

I tried to build a dynamic method call, but it dosent work ...

```
 $matchList = [ 'match1', 'match2', 'match3', 'match4' ];

      $query->where('Column', 'Like', $hobbiesList[0]);

      if(count($matchList) > 1)
      {
          for($i = 1; $i < count($matchList); $i++)
          {
              $query->{orWhere('Column', 'Like', $matchList[$i])}();
          }
      }
```

The problem is I got a match list and for this list I must build a dynamic query statement in Larvel 5.1.

Can anyone help me or explain where my mistake is ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to do anything complicated, just use this:

```
for($i = 1; $i < count($matchList); $i++)
{
  $query->orWhere('Column', 'Like', $matchList[$i]);
}
```

You will also most likely want to use `"%".$matchList[$i]."%"` instead of just `$matchList[$i]` as the value.

Comment: Thank's .

My problem now is, that my result contains **all** matches, but I want that my result must only contains on of the parameter's from the match list.

Comment: Can you edit the question and show what results you're getting instead of what you want?

Comment: I'am an idiot, everything is working correct ... my mistake.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't need to use wildcards then you should use `wherein`:

```
$query->whereIn('Column', $matchList);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$result = $model->where(function($query) use($where,$tj){
            foreach ($where as $wh){
                if($tj==1){
                    $query->where($wh[0],$wh[1],$wh[2]);
                }else {
                    $query->orWhere($wh[0], $wh[1], $wh[2]);
                }
            }
        })->orderBy($sort,$order)->offset($from)->limit($rows)->get();
```